# Functional error squigglies not showing up in VSCODE (vim extension)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently started using the vim extension in vscode and it has eliminated argument checking and red squigglies when I have it enabled. Any one know how to get it to check arguments again? It still detects semantically incorrect Python but doesn't check the function definitions for some reason.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not an image.